# Write structure to a file && read structure to a dynamicly allocated memory

Tags: c, structure, fwrite, allocation, fread

I am trying to write structure to a file and then read structure to a dynamicly allocated memory.
If this algorhythm even works, I'm not sure about fread function... Is it able to read all structures in file written this way and store it to *ptr, so I can access it from memory ?
Is there better way to do this?

```
 typedef struct num {
    int num1;
    int num2;   
}NR;

void write() {
    int successfullywritten;
    FILE *f;
    struct num nr;
    f = fopen("dat.txt", "a");
    printf("Enter first number\n");
    scanf("%d", &nr.num1);
    printf("Enter second number\n");
    scanf("%d", &nr.num2);
    successfullywritten=fwrite(&nr, sizeof num, 1, f);
    printf("Succesfully written: %d\n", successfullywritten);
    fclose(f);
}

void read() {

    int size, entrys,i,successfullyread;
    FILE *f;
    f = fopen("dat.txt", "r");
    struct num *ptr;
    fseek(f, 0L, SEEK_END);
    size = ftell(f);
    printf("\nSize of file dat.txt: %d\n", size);
    entrys = size / sizeof(num);
    ptr = (num*)malloc(entrys * sizeof(num));
    successfullyread=fread(ptr, sizeof(num), entrys, f);
    printf("sucessfully Read: %d\n", successfullyread);
    for (i = 0;i < entrys; i++) {
        /*fread((ptr+i), sizeof(ptr), 1, f);*/
        printf("%d  ", (*(ptr)).num1);
        printf("%d\n", (*(ptr)).num2);

    }
    printf("\n");printf("\n");

    fclose(f);
}

int main() {
    int n;
    while(1){
       printf("Chooose action:\n1) write to file\n2) read from file:\n");
       scanf("%d", &n);
       switch (n) {
          case 1:
             write();
             break;
          case 2:
             read();
             break;
       }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: actually it is not .txt it is .dat

Comment: Are you interested in storing the member values of a struct in a file, or are you interested in storing the struct itself?  Either way, a _list_ approach may serve your interest better.

Comment: Ideally, only store in memory what is required for current processing, unless you know you need it later. And have you functions *return* a value indicating any error instead of *print* that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, There are lot of simple typo mistakes like

- There is confusion between typedefed name or structure name. This
  `entrys = size / sizeof(num);` should be
  `entrys = size / sizeof(struct num);`
- This `ptr = (num*)malloc(entrys * sizeof(num));` should be `ptr = malloc(entrys * sizeof(struct num));` . Avoid casting result of `malloc()`.

Secondly, after finding the `size`, you forgot to move `f` to beginning of file. for e.g

```
fseek(f, 0L, SEEK_END);
size = ftell(f);
fseek(f, 0L, SEEK_SET); /* you forgot to add this */
```

Thirdly, you are data into file using `fwrite()` use `ab` instead of `a` mode
& while reading using `fread()` use `rb` instead of `r`.

Also after reading from file you need to free the `ptr` to avoid memory leakage.

```
free(ptr);
```

Here is the sample code

```
typedef struct num {
        int num1;
        int num2;
}NR;
void my_write(void) {
        int successfullywritten;
        FILE *f;
        struct num nr;
        f = fopen("dat.txt", "ab");
        printf("Enter first number\n");
        scanf("%d", &nr.num1);
        printf("Enter second number\n");
        scanf("%d", &nr.num2);
        successfullywritten=fwrite(&nr, sizeof(nr), 1, f);
        printf("Succesfully written: %d\n", successfullywritten);
        fclose(f);
}

void my_read(void) {

        int size, entrys,i,successfullyread;
        FILE *f;
        f = fopen("dat.txt", "rb");
        struct num *ptr;
        fseek(f, 0L, SEEK_END);
        size = ftell(f);
        fseek(f, 0L, SEEK_SET);
        printf("\nSize of file dat.txt: %d\n", size);
        entrys = size / sizeof(struct num);

        ptr = malloc(entrys * sizeof(struct num));
        successfullyread=fread(ptr, sizeof(struct num), 2, f);
        printf("sucessfully Read: %d\n", successfullyread);

        for (i = 0;i < entrys; i++) {
                /*fread((ptr+i), sizeof(ptr), 1, f);*/
                printf("%d  ", ptr[i].num1);
                printf("%d\n", ptr[i].num2);

        }
        free(ptr);
        printf("\n");printf("\n");
        fclose(f);
}
int main(void) {
        int n;
        while(1){
                printf("Chooose action:\n1) write to file\n2) read from file:\n");
                scanf("%d", &n);
                switch (n) {
                        case 1:
                                my_write();
                                break;
                        case 2:
                                my_read();
                                break;
                }
        }
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you certain the statement `size = ftell(f);` is providing what is needed?  (given its subsequent use)

Comment: No, I am not sure. Firstly file contains binary data so I am doubtful about this formula `entrys = size / sizeof(struct num);`

Comment: Yes I too have same doubt. Feel free to edit if its needed.

Comment: As `ftell()` returns `long`, `long size` can work for large files that fail `int size`.